# Can `lein ring server` command have other params?

Tags: clojure, ring

I would like to start a server like this:

```
lein ring server 3000 local
lein ring server 3000 test
```

where `local` or `test` could be read by my app to run with different `env`. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not really sure why all the downvotes or votes to close. The question is terse, certainly, but it's relatively clear what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @PaulButcher: please edit the question accordingly, then.

Comment: I'm not sure it needs editing. I understand it and have answered it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case is exactly what Leiningen [profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md) are for. For example

```
lein with-profile test ring server
```